# Acts_as_follower - Following model on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up acts_as_follower so Users can follow Groups. It all works so far but I'd like the creator of a Group (the author a.k.a the current_user) to automatically become a follower of that group upon creation.

Really, is there a way to execute another controllers action from within the groups controller? (.follow)

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
        current_user.follow(@group)
        respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @group }
      format.js
    end
    end

    def destroy
        @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
        current_user.stop_following(@group)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @group }
      format.js
    end
    end
end
```

groups_controller.rb

```
def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.author_id = current_user.id

if @group.save
    flash.notice = "Group '#{@group.title}' Successfully Created!"
    redirect_to group_path(@group)
else
    flash.alert = "Group not created!"
    render 'new'
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I went back and figured this out. You can run the method fine, just after the model saves:

groups_controller.rb

```
def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.author_id = current_user.id

    if @group.save
        flash.notice = "Group '#{@group.title}' Successfully Created!"
        redirect_to group_path(@group)
        @group.author.follow(@group)
    else
        flash.alert = "Group not created!"
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: You can further refine it by moving that to the model in an after create callback.